# Using group by in SET clause

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update a column of a table so that is equal to the count of something in another table. Like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET TOTAL = (SELECT COUNT(f1)
             FROM TABLE2
             GROUP BY f2);
```

But I keep getting sub query returns more than 1 row, and I can't think of how to fix it.

**UPDATE** (copied from the comment)

> f2 is the relation between TABLE and TABLE2 – Thomasd d

Comment: your subquery is returning more than 1 row, meaning that there is more than one value for `f2` in `TABLE2`. to fix your query you need to modify the subquery so that it only returns a single value

Comment: Do the tables have a relation?

Comment: it looks also like a very dangerous query because you have no WHERE clause, which means that, if you finally succeed, all rows from the table will get this new total, which is hardly logical

Comment: f2 is the relation between TABLE and TABLE2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE t1
SET total = ( SELECT COUNT(f1)
              FROM t2
              WHERE t1.f2 = t2.f2 );
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=91de17deff657f66fa54b42fe20ed3c5

Add `WHERE total IS NULL` if you do not need to recalculate values for rows which have a value already.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment

> f2 is the relation between TABLE and TABLE2

you probably want something like this

```
UPDATE TABLE T1, (SELECT f2, COUNT(F1) cnt FROM TABLE2 GROUP BY f2) T2
SET T1.TOTAL = T2.cnt
WHERE T1.f2=T2.f2
```

adapt `T1.f2` if necessary

Answer (score -1):

Your subquery is returning multiple values and your SET statement is only expecting one. This might fix your code if that is what you are looking for.

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET TOTAL = (SELECT COUNT(f1)
FROM TABLE2)
```

Comment: Relation between tables is not taken into account.